# Method calling stored procedure took 80% cpu

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, performance, jdbc

There's a method which run stored procedure alone with parameter. After I run the program in debug mode using VisualVM, I found that method took over 80% cpu.

The method is just to run stored procedure. The stored procedure includes to insert each record into another tables using while loop.

Here's my method :

```
public void addRecs(String user, int Param) {
    try {
            conn.setCatalog("MyDBName");
            CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("{call sp_addRecords(?,?,?)}");
            stmt.setString(1, user);
            stmt.setInt(2, Param);
            stmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.INTEGER);
            stmt.execute();
            int rowCount = stmt.getInt(3);
            System.out.println(rowCount + " records has added into Record Table!");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: check for parameter sniffing in your sp - reference link : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/turgays/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-possible-workarounds/

Comment: Are you saying that while it was sitting on the `execute()` call, waiting for the database to return, it was consuming 80% of your CPU? Or are you saying that you profiled the code, and 80% of time was spent in the `addRecs()` method? The former sounds very unlikely, but it is what you said *("over 80% cpu")*. The latter means that you should analyze the `sp_addRecords` stored procedure, since it's slowness has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: I suggest you close off your CallableStatemant in a try-with-resource block to avoid any memory leaks.

Comment: yah that try-with-resource block is something new to me. I know how to use but I'm not confident enough to use it :(

Comment: can u spare me example for it?